# Android app compatibility issue

Tags: android

I developed an android app. Its manifest is very simple and copied below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.siddjain.jainaartis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="true" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayForm"
            class=".Aarti" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The Play store reports this app to be incompatible with many devices. Specifically, it reports it to be incompatible with **Samsung GT-S5570** which is my phone. *I installed the app onto my phone manually, and it works.*

The developer console gives this message:
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.touchscreen
This application is available to over 266 devices.

The [device availability dialog](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=go&answer=1286017) lists Samsung GT-S5570 as incompatible.
**How can I fix the compatibility issue? What is there in my manifest that is causing the app to be classified as incompatible with Samsung GT-S5570?** As mentioned earlier, I have checked the app works on my phone.

The specs of the phone are available [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_mini_s5570-3725.php) btw. It has a display resolution of 240x320 pixels and has Froyo (android v2.2.1)

Comment: "This app is incompatible with your galaxy s" - Galaxy S, Android 4.0.3, Slovenian carrier.

Comment: It must be somewhere in the `android:reqFiveWayNav="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to fix this using following manifest (support for small screens has to be declared explicitly). The number of devices to which the app is available increased from 266 to 1272.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.siddjain.jainaartis"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayForm"
            class=".Aarti" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a carrier restriction. The play store filters apps via known information about your device (screen size, OS, carrier), but not if it can install and/or work or not. It would be a nightmare for development (and non play store apps) if you couldn't install because it checked compatibility. 
How long ago did you add the app? If you just added it, it takes several hours for it to propagate and become available.

I see it uses 5 way nav. Does your application use this (I assume so) and does it work in your application?

Comment: Also your device has a ldpi/small screen. You might consider declaring that it is supported in your manifest.